# Edit form for data stored in Vuex and mapped as computed computed properties

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I have a form component used for client registration and edit. When the form component is created I first check if the URL has an ID or not to determine what type of form to display. If the form has no ID ( meaning register new client ) all fields should be empty. And if the URL has an ID then I load the client info via an Axios request then store the data in Vuex and display the data in the fields for modifications.

```html
     <Form enctype="multipart/form-data" @submit="$emit('submit')">
         <validation-provider
                     name="Compnay name"
                          >
                      <v-text-field
                      v-model="details.company_name"
                              label="Compnay name"
                            />
                  <span class="text-sm text-red-500">{{ errors[0] }}</span>
          </validation-provider>
     <validation-provider
                     name="Compnay name"
                          >
                      <v-text-field
                      v-model="details.email"
                              label="Compnay email"
                            />
                  <span class="text-sm text-red-500">{{ errors[0] }}</span>
          </validation-provider>
     <validation-provider
                     name="Compnay phone"
                          >
                      <v-text-field
                      v-model="details.phone"
                              label="Compnay name"
                            />
                  <span class="text-sm text-red-500">{{ errors[0] }}</span>
          </validation-provider>
        ...
```

Then I set data properties here

```js
    data: function () {
        return {
          details: {
            type: Object,
            default: () => ({})
    
          },
```

In `create` I did `await this.$store.dispatch("clients/getClientById", { id: id})` to get the client info

**The challenge I'm facing** is after I get the client from `computed` I couldn't find a way to add them in v-model to send them with `FormData` or edit them. Can somebody guide me, please.

I attempted to do this. but I got an error saying `Error: [vuex] do not mutate vuex store state outside mutation handlers.` Once I type something in the field

```js
    async getClientById(id){
          await this.$store.dispatch("clients/getClientById", {
            id: id})
            .then(res => {
            if (res.status === 200 ){
              let clientData = res.data.data
              this.details = clientData
              this.status = clientData.status
            }
          })
```

Comment: So I guess your Vuex action `clients/getClientById` is storing the result of the request (`res.data.data`) in the state right?

Comment: Yes it stores client data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### 1st

Your "last attempt" doesn't work because of objects are [Passed by Reference in JS](https://medium.com/@jordanmmartin/js-pass-by-value-vs-pass-by-reference-5a8c9ebf4d14) so `this.details` in the end points to the object inside Vuex state and changing data inside Vuex directly outside of a mutation (by `v-model` in this case) is prohibited in strict mode (which is a **good thing**)

You can fix it by making the copy of the object (will work only if members are simple values, not objects as spread operator is doing only shallow copy) ie:

```js
if (res.status === 200 ){
          let clientData = { ...res.data.data }
          this.details = clientData
          this.status = clientData.status
        }
```

### On forms

In most Create/Edit forms you want some features:

1. Form has Save/Cancel buttons so the user has a choice to "undo all the changes by single click"
2. Validation - "Save" operation is allowed only if data entered is valid

Best way to do it imho is to make the form so that all data are first copied from Vuex into local `data` of the form component and all inputs are bound to the local data. This has multiple benefits:

1. When user types something, only local data changes and original data in Vuex are intact. Implementing "Cancel" button is then as easy as simply closing the form (and discarding all local data).
2. Implementing "Save" is also easy - just check all validations are passing and then use mutation to `commit` changed data into Vuex store
3. If the data under edit (stored in Vuex) are used in multiple places in your app, other "places" (components) doesn't "see" intermediate data which can be invalid during editing (for example you have two numbers in the store - A and B. Editing form for them and other component which displays result of `A/B`. If editing form is bound to the Vuex data directly and user changes B to 0, form displays validation error but your display component still sees the 0 in the store and throws an error)
4. Form component code is simpler because binding to local reactive data is much easier then [binding form controls directly to Vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/forms.html)

Comment: Thank you for your help. The data will be used in multiple components. I’m trying to find a good way to access them in store and avoid making requests in the component

Comment: That's fine, I don't know why you checking response status in your method. Just dispatch an action and let the action return the "clientData" object (returning existing object if it's in the store already or make a server request). Making copy of the data in editing form is a "good way". In most cases you don't want the form controls to change Vuex data directly anyway but commit changes made to a local copy only if/when user clicks "Submit" button

Comment: Learned a lot from your answer. Thank you dear Michal. May I ask what you meany by " you don't want the form controls to change Vuex data directly anyway but commit changes made to a local copy only if/when user clicks "Submit" button"